# PL/SQL Procedure - Compilation Error ORA-24344

Tags: oracle

I am unable to create a stored procedure in Oracle DB thru Aqua Data Studio while access data from other schemas.
My schemas: RS

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_Vtest
(v_test_details out SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
open v_test_details for 
SELECT * FROM AS.v_test_table;
END PROC_Vtest;
```

> Error: ORA-24344: success with compilation error

how to solve this issue?

I tried to execute procedure without error message.
I am expecting to create a stored procedure in Oracle db and data is located in other's schemas.

Comment: `select * from user_errors`

Comment: it says
PLS-00201: identifier 'V_REGISTRY__DETAILS' must be declared
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: There's no such identifier in the code

Comment: Hope you understood my question. Can you please send me an example syntax to create a stored procedure in my Schema [RS] but data located in different Schema [AS.TableA]

Answer (score 0):

> Can you please send me an example syntax to create a stored procedure in my Schema [RS] but data located in different Schema [AS.TableA]

In that case, user `AS` has to grant (at least) `select` privilege to your user (`RS`). If you're about to use other user's table in named PL/SQL procedures (which is what you have), then such a grant has to be done directly to you, not via role.

So:

```
connect as/its_password
grant select on v_test_Table to rs;
```

In your own schema, maybe you'd rather create a function (or a procedure, doesn't really matter):

```
connect rs/its_password
create or replace function f_test return sys_refcursor
is
  retval sys_refcursor;
begin
  open rc for select * from as.v_test_table;
  return rc;
end;
/
select f_test from dual;
```